# Python script for closing impala queries. I am using urllib and json libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, impala, cloudera-cdh

I am using a python script to close impala queries. The script is working well with string variables, but I am not able to write a logic for string + integer variables. 
The variables I am using are
If Status = "Finished" or "Exception" 
and Waiting = True
Then close the queries using urllib. 
However, I want help in including integer variable. Integer variable will be like 15m10sec or 15sec10ms.

Below is Code:

```
import urllib, json
from datetime import datetime

nodes = ["node1.com:1202",   #example destination servers
      "node2.com:1202",
      "node3.com:1202",       
    ]

for i, datanode in enumerate(nodes):
 print("Checking {}: {}".format(i, datanode))
 try:
     response = urllib.urlopen(datanode + "queries?json")
     data = json.loads(response.read())

     if data["num_waiting_queries"] > 0:
         print(data["num_waiting_queries"])
         for in_flight_query in data["in_flight_queries"]:
             if in_flight_query["waiting"] is True and in_flight_query['state'] == "FINISHED" or  "EXCEPTION" and in_flight_query['duration'][:2] > 15:  #I have included the duration here but it not working as expected. I guess the logic is incorrect. Code works after removing 'duration'.
                 cancel_url = datanode + "cancel_query?query_id={}".format(in_flight_query['query_id'])
                 print(cancel_url)
                 response = urllib.urlopen(cancel_url)

 except IOError:
     print("Skipping {}: {}".format(i, datanode))

 except Exception as e:
     print(e)
```

[image]

json objects:

```
This the json script,I want use variable "duration" from it. 
"in_flight_queries": [
    {
        "effective_user": "user4",
        "default_db": "testdb",
        "stmt": "select * from table",
        "stmt_type": "QUERY",
        "start_time": "2018-06-18 01:04:12.558731000",
        "end_time": "00:00:00",
        "duration": "30m34s",
        "progress": "16 / 30 (53.3333%)",
        "state": "FINISHED",
        "rows_fetched": 10,
        "query_id": "7243:954ed9414b96abaf",
        "last_event": "First row fetched",
        "waiting": true,
        "executing": false,
        "waiting_time": "30m30s"
    }
```

Comment: can you show where does `However, I want help in including integer variable. Integer variable will be like 15m10sec or 15sec10ms` fit in code? it is a bit unclear: what variable do you mention and also `15m10sec `is not integer

Comment: 15m10sec will keep on changing like time.

Comment: where do you want to include integer time in your code?

Comment: in the same line `if in_flight_query["waiting"] is True and in_flight_query['state'] == "FINISHED" or  "EXCEPTION"`

Comment: so where is this integer varaible coming from and what is it compated with?

Comment: As shown in the image which is below the code, the variable is **Duration** it will keep on changing with time until closed. In the image **Duration = 35m10s**

Comment: how do you access duration in your code?

Comment: We access application through api. The variable is "duration". Is there a way to convert the duration to string? I am not able to figure out the solution.

Comment: are you asking: how we can convert '15m30sec' string to an integer indicating seconds, is that your question?

Comment: It is coming from json script. I added the json script for your reference.

Comment: I see, it is much clearer this way

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion, I think you can extract the time with a function below and compare it later in `if` statement:

```
from datetime import datetime

def extract_seconds(text: str):
    pat = '%Mm%Ss' # convenient reference: http://strftime.org/    
    try:
        x = datetime.strptime(text, pat)
    except ValueError:    
        raise ValueError('Cannot extract time from {} with {}'.format(x, pat))
    return x.minute * 60 + x.second    

assert extract_seconds('30m34s') == 1834
```

If you are willing to work with `datetime` object, this is even shorter:

```
def extract(text: str):
    pat = '%Mm%Ss' # convenient reference: http://strftime.org/    
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(text, pat).time()
    except ValueError:    
        raise ValueError('Cannot extract time from {} with {}'.format(x, pat))
```

Comment: Thank you Evgeny. However, this will not work for me. I am looking for something like `in_flight_query[['duration'[2:3]]] == 'm' and in_flight_query[[int('duration'[:2])]] > 15:`  But its not working as expected

Comment: @Michael, you cannot be serious about `in_flight_query[['duration'[2:3]]] == 'm' and in_flight_query[[int('duration'[:2])]] > 15:`, use   `extract(in_flight_query['duration']).second > 15`.

Comment: I am seeing following error `name 'extract' is not defined` after using  `extract(in_flight_query['duration']).second > 15`

Comment: did you pu the `def extract(...` code somewhere in you program before you use this function?

Comment: I did not put `def extract(...` code anywhere else.

Comment: Sounds bad for your code and your program. Try get someone working in pair with you, this way you probably can achieve better result in your refactoring.

Comment: Try something like this: elif in_flight_query["waiting"] is True and in_flight_query['state'] == "FINISHED" and in_flight_query['duration'].startswith(('2h')):
                    cancel_url = datanode + "cancel_query?query_id={0}".format(in_flight_query['query_id'])